# how to create a copy of branch with new branch name cvsd

Tags: git, cvs

I am using cvsd from the last two year and this utility amazing. now their
is need to of creating a branch which had the latest stable branch code.
am kind of confused how to do this.

let me explain my problem. I have a current working branch which is most
stable "September-2015". now i want to do some buggy work. for that i
want to create a new branch "May-2016" which has the latest stable
branch code. so what ever the enhancement will go into May-2016. so that
my stable code will not distrube.

Please suggest how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In git you simply create a new branch based upon the existing one.

```
# Checkout the branch which you want as your base branch
git checkout <current>

# create the new branch out of the existing branch
git branch -b <new name>
```

Comment: is this same in case of cvsd .... i guess in cvsd we can create direct copy of latest branch with new name. without checkout

Comment: checkout is just be sure you are on the right branch

Comment: @CodeWizrd Got the solution ..... i didn't know this is so simple .. actually my server is on linux .... simply login into my cvs via shell and fire few simple command of tags creation . **cvs rtag -r Tagname -b Branchname my_module**